# Processing HttpPostedFile.InputStream before saving using SaveAs()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, stream

I need to check if a file is compressed before saving it.  I have created the following extension method to check if the file is compressed using `ZipFile` (from the [SharpLibZip](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) library):

```
public static bool IsCompressed(this HttpPostedFile postedFile)
{
    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;

    using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(stream))
    {
        return zipFile.TestArchive(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `HttpPostedFile.SaveAs()` it saves the file as 0kb:

```
if(uploadedFile.IsCompressed())
{
    uploadedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    uploadedFile.SaveAs(physicalZipFile.FullName);
}
```

This has something to do with using the stream in `IsCompressed()`.  I have tried seeking to the beginning before saving but the problem remains.

Could someone please explain the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this... here is my solution:

Using ILSpy I decompiled the assembly to find that `ZipFile.Dispose()` actually closes the stream.  There is other cleanup code so I wouldn't recommend not disposing of the `ZipFile` instance.

On the other hand, `ZipArchive` (`System.IO.Compression`) actually has the following overloaded constructor:

```
public ZipArchive(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, bool leaveOpen)
```

Setting `leaveOpen` to `true` will leave the stream open after the instance has been correctly disposed.